# Create multi-dimensional array from one-dimensional with ID and ParentID

Tags: php, arrays, nested, associative-array

This is to create a menu with submenus.

If it's of any help I created a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o1gkb9nw/1/) to visualize what I want (in HTML).

I have this one-dimensional array with no specific order:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: AAA },
  { id: 2, name: BBB, parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 3, name: CCC, parent_id: 2 },
  { id: 4, name: DDD, parent_id: 6 },
  { id: 5, name: EEE },
  { id: 6, name: FFF, parent_id: 1 },
  { id: 7, name: GGG, parent_id: 2 },
]
```

And want to create this, basically:

> - IF item has a parent_id
>
>   - put it under that parent_id inside key childs: [ .. ]
> - ELSE
>
>   - Put item directly under new array

This has to be able to support an *infinite* amount of nested childs.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: AAA,
    childs: [{
      id: 2,
      name: BBB,
      childs: [{
        id: 3,
        name: CCC
      }, {
        id: 7,
        name: GGG
      }]
    }, {
      id: 6,
      name: FFF,
      childs: [{
        id: 4,
        name: DDD
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: EEE
  }
]
```

Since the order of the initial array is unknown, and the parent_ids can come BEFORE the actual parent inside that array I don't know how to do it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the array several times:

1. Loop over the array and check for all items without a `parent_id`. They are rootlevel items. Put them in a new array. Remove them from the original array.
2. Loop over the array and check for all items if their `parent_id` is in the new array. If it is, put it into the new array as child of the `parent_id`'s item. Remove them from the original array.
3. Repeat with 2 until the original array is empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cant get it to work though. Do you know an example I can check?